# react-jsonschema-form updown widget minimum registered but not enforced

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

[image: Updown Widget React developer tool screenshot]

The updown widgets schema exactly matches that of the [example playground](https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/) but unlike the playground, I am able to decrease the value to below the minimum. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem described in open issue for a different widget:

https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/issues/1647